# MemCached overrides dotnetcore default session

Tags: c#, .net-core, memcached

We are using mvc application with dotnet core version 2.1. recently we moved to use memcached for store some data, but problem comes with this is: earlier we were using httpcontext.session and its work fine.

after applied memcached, i am not able to get values from session. its always null.Values get/set successfully in same action but not across action.

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential 
               cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddEnyimMemcached();
        services.AddSession();

        app.UseEnyimMemcached();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
```

---

Comment: How are you getting values from the session then?

Comment: @DavidG
HttpContext.Session.Set("google", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some"));
byte[] arr;
HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("google", out arr);

Comment: What happens if you change the sequence of adding session and memcached ?

Comment: @mukeshjoshi : Its give me same behaviour. But we diagnosed it. Main issue in DOTNETCore version 2.0 SDK.
If we move to 2.2 then it works fine.